# Ansible set_fact dictionary of lists

Tags: python, ansible

I have this code, i'm trying to combine two lists into a dictionary but no luck. Im new to ansible.

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    service_status: {}
    location: 
  tasks: 
    - name:
      command: echo {{ item }}
      register: excecute
      with_items:
        - hello
        - world

    - name: Setting  facts
      set_fact:
        service_status: "{{service_status | combine({ 'command_status' : {'service': item.item , 'status': item.failed }}, recursive=True) }}"  
      with_items: "{{ excecute.results }}"

    - name:
      debug:
        msg: "{{ hostvars['localhost'] | json_query('service_status') }}"
```

the output i got is

TASK [debug]

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "command_status": {
            "service": "world",
            "status": false
        }
    }
}
```

but i want the output like below

```
 "command_status": [
    {
        "service": "hello",
        "status": false
    },
    {
        "service": "world",
        "status": false
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop is not necessary to create the list of dictionaries with the selected attributes of the results. Instead, use [*json_query multiselect hash*](https://jmespath.readthedocs.io/en/latest/specification.html#multiselect-hash) and create the list of dictionaries *cmd_stats*. Then combine the dictionary in one step. For example, the tasks below

```yaml
    - name: Setting  facts
      set_fact:
        service_status: "{{ service_status|
                            combine({'command_status': cmd_stats}) }}"
      vars:
        cmd_stats: "{{ excecute.results|
                       json_query('[].{service: item, status: failed}') }}"

    - debug:
        var: service_status
```

give

```yaml
  service_status:
    command_status:
    - service: hello
      status: false
    - service: world
      status: false
```

Notes:

- *hostvars* and *json_query* are not necessary to display the variable *service_status*.